# Can't export fromIni from @aws-sdk/credential-providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-credentials

I'm working on a React/Node.js app and I'm trying to read my IAM User credentials from ~/.aws/credentials file. I am trying to use fromIni from the @aws-sdk/credential-providers node package. According to the [AWS SDK v3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.html#fromini), I can do the following:

```js
import { fromIni } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"; // ES6 import
// const { fromIni } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-providers"); // CommonJS import

const client = new FooClient({
  credentials: fromIni({
    // Optional. The configuration profile to use. If not specified, the provider will use the value
    // in the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable or a default of `default`.
    profile: "profile",
    // Optional. The path to the shared credentials file. If not specified, the provider will use
    // the value in the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable or a default of
    // `~/.aws/credentials`.
    filepath: "~/.aws/credentials",
    // Optional. The path to the shared config file. If not specified, the provider will use the
    // value in the `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable or a default of `~/.aws/config`.
    configFilepath: "~/.aws/config",
    // Optional. A function that returns a a promise fulfilled with an MFA token code for the
    // provided MFA Serial code. If a profile requires an MFA code and `mfaCodeProvider` is not a
    // valid function, the credential provider promise will be rejected.
    mfaCodeProvider: async (mfaSerial) => {
      return "token";
    },
    // Optional. Custom STS client configurations overriding the default ones.
    clientConfig: { region },
  }),
});
```

But when I try this in my index.js file:

```js
import { fromIni } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';

const createLink = {
  url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: config.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    credentials: fromIni()
  }
};
```

and then run `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
export 'fromIni' (imported as 'fromIni') was not found in '@aws-sdk/credential-providers' (possible exports: fromCognitoIdentity, fromCognitoIdentityPool, fromTemporaryCredentials, fromWebToken)
```

It seems like the function I want isn't exported from the package but the documentation says otherwise.

Edit:
The output to `@aws-sdk/credential-providers @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini`

```
port-dashboard@0.1.0 C:\Users\kshang\Documents\pov-ui       
├─┬ @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider@3.79.0        
│ ├─┬ @aws-sdk/client-sts@3.79.0
│ │ └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.79.0
│ │   └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.79.0
│ └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.79.0
│   └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.79.0
├─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-providers@3.79.0
│ ├─┬ @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity@3.79.0
│ │ └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.79.0
│ │   └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.79.0 deduped   
│ └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.79.0
└─┬ aws-amplify@4.3.20
  ├─┬ @aws-amplify/analytics@5.2.5
  │ └─┬ @aws-sdk/client-firehose@3.6.1
  │   └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.6.1
  │     ├── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.6.1
  │     └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-process@3.6.1      
  │       └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.6.1 deduped
  └─┬ @aws-amplify/geo@1.3.1
    └─┬ @aws-sdk/client-location@3.48.0
      └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.48.0
        └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.48.0
```

Comment: What's the output of `npm list @aws-sdk/credential-providers @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini`?

Comment: Just FYI, everything you have set should be automatic by the SDK. You are just being explicit, but the default behavior is to read the files you have specified.

Comment: @jordanm I am trying to use Apollo Client in my app and AWS provides a package to do [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js#using-authorization-and-subscription-links-with-apollo-client-v3-no-offline-support). I think I am supposed to explicitly provide my AWS credentials to my ApolloLink object.

Comment: I am not familiar with these services, but I don't see any IAM authentication in the documentation you linked. It appears to use an appsync API key for authentication, not an IAM keypair.

Comment: @jordanm it's the commented out section:

const auth = {
  type: appSyncConfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
  apiKey: appSyncConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey,
  // jwtToken: async () => token, // Required when you use Cognito UserPools OR OpenID Connect. token object is obtained previously
  // credentials: async () => credentials, // Required when you use IAM-based auth.
};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: After doing more [research](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3392) and talking to some AWS Experts, it turns out we'll need to use Amazon Cognito in order to get credentials for our Browser based app.

---

I get the same error trying to use `fromIni()` for a simple `CreateInvalidationCommand` using the [CloudFrontClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudfront/index.html).

Trying to configure the client without the `credentials` key results in a `Error: Credential is missing`

My current workaround for developing locally is using a .env.local file, and using the [accessKeyId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudfront/modules/credentials.html#accesskeyid-1) and [secretAccessKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudfront/modules/credentials.html#secretaccesskey-1) properties for my config:

```
const cloudfront = new CloudFrontClient({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  region: "us-east-1",
});
```

Which is obviously not ideal, but it works locally for testing and development.

I also wanted to note that [fromEnv()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.html#fromenv) is also missing from the exports. Which causes issues with this workaround in EC2 instances.

Either way, hoping to see this resolved in an update soon.

```
cache-invalidator@0.1.0 /Users/miguelmaldonado/Desktop/projects/prototypes/cache-invalidator
├─┬ @aws-sdk/client-cloudfront@3.85.0
│ └─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node@3.85.0
│   └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.85.0 deduped
└─┬ @aws-sdk/credential-providers@3.85.0
  └── @aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini@3.85.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this similar issue while trying to run locally with reactjs and webpack. I was able to get around this short coming by doing the following.

I updated my webpack config to read the credentials from the file using os, fs and ini.

```
const os = require("os");
const fs = require('fs');
const ini = require('ini');

const userInfo = os.userInfo()

const creds = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(userInfo.homedir + '\\.aws\\credentials', 'utf8').replace('[yourprofile]', ''));
```

and then added these values to the environment variables in the webpack plugins section

```
plugins: [
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: JSON.stringify(creds.aws_session_token),
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY: JSON.stringify(creds.aws_access_key_id),
      AWS_SECRET_KEY: JSON.stringify(creds.aws_secret_access_key),
    }
  })
]
```

In my s3 code i have the following

```
if (env === 'development') {
        const agent: HttpsProxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent({ proxy: new URL("http://proxy.yourproxy.net:8443") })
        const creds = {
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY ? process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY : '',
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY ? process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY : '',
            sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
        };

        console.log(creds);
        return new S3Client(
            {
                region: REGION,
                credentials: creds,
                requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
                    httpAgent: agent,
                    httpsAgent: agent
                })
            }
        );
    }
```