# @aws-sdk/credential-providers does not provide an export named 'fromNodeProviderChain'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, credential-providers

I am trying to configure the AWS JavaScript SDK for use with Node.js. I am trying to establish connectivity between a React app running locally, and a Lambda, using the @aws-sdk/client-lambda and @aws-sdk/credential-providers packages. I am following this AWS documentation to configure my Lambda client: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html .

I am creating a session token using the AWS CLI, with the command:
`aws cli login -s`, and then selecting my preferred IAM role. The output of this command is:

```
Assuming role arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/12345-my-role-name as NAEAST\MyUserID on app-dev-12345-myorg (1234567890) in region  us-east-1...
```

According to the docs, I should be able to use the default provider chain to access this token that I just created:

> AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 provides a default credential provider chain in Node.js, so you are not required to supply a credential provider explicitly. The default credential provider chain attempts to resolve the credentials from a variety of different sources in a given precedence, until a credential is returned from the one of the sources. You can find the credential provider chain for SDK for JavaScript V3 here.

I am assuming this default provider chain is the `fromNodeProviderChain`. The code they give to use this credential provider is:

```
import { fromNodeProviderChain } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"; // ES6 import
// const { fromNodeProviderChain } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-providers") // CommonJS import
const credentialProvider = fromNodeProviderChain({
  //...any input of fromEnv(), fromSSO(), fromTokenFile(), fromIni(),
  // fromProcess(), fromInstanceMetadata(), fromContainerMetadata()
  // Optional. Custom STS client configurations overriding the default ones.
  clientConfig: { region },
});
```

I add this to my bare-bones React app, like so:

```
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';
import { fromNodeProviderChain } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';

const HomePage = () => {
  const region = 'us-east-1';
  const credentialProvider = fromNodeProviderChain({
    //...any input of fromEnv(), fromSSO(), fromTokenFile(), fromIni(),
    // fromProcess(), fromInstanceMetadata(), fromContainerMetadata()
    // Optional. Custom STS client configurations overriding the default ones.
    clientConfig: { region },
  });
  const config = {
    region,
    credentials: credentialProvider
  };
  const client = new LambdaClient(config);
...
...
...
```

However, I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@aws-sdk_credential-providers.js?t=1708529564599&v=0778e0cf does not provide an export named 'fromNodeProviderChain' (Home.tsx:4:10)
```

What is going on here? I am able to import the Lambda client using ES6 syntax, so that is not the issue. I am also able to import other credential providers from the `@aws-sdk/credential-providers` package, such as:

```
import { fromCognitoIdentity } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';
import { fromTemporaryCredentials } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers'; // ES6 import
```

These do not throw an import error.
I would very much like to use `fromNodeProviderChain` because that seems by far the easiest to set up, and it should be able to grab my session token.

Comment: What is the version of "@aws-sdk/credential-providers" you are using in package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so was misunderstanding what the docs meant by 'Node app' and 'browser.' I assumed that because React uses Node.js, it is a 'Node app' in this context but it is actually just a 'browser' app. The docs are quite clear that `fromNodeProviderChain` is not usable in a browser app. This is the issue.

For local development purposes, I am using a workaround like the ones described here: [Can't export fromIni from @aws-sdk/credential-providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72088326/cant-export-fromini-from-aws-sdk-credential-providers?rq=2) . When I deploy this app, I intend to use AWS Cognito.